# Center row in CSS Grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm creating a 4x3 grid layout and want the second row to be centered since the top row has four elements.

Something like this:

[image]

**Demo code:**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, **you can't** as a 4 column grid...what you have there **is not a GRID**. I'd use flexbox or perhaps try adapting a 8(?) column grid.

Answer (score 5):

Easy to do it with `flex`

and to center use `justify-content: center;` to set width use `flex: 0 0 cala(20% - 40px);`:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 0 0 calc(20% - 40px);
padding: 20px;
margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>  
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

An **EIGHT** column grid is actually what you are after.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  grid-column: span 2
}

.grid-item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
</div>
```